# UIDocumentPickerController does not occupy entire screen in IOS14

Tags: ios14, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am using following code to import files,

```
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        let supportedTypes: [UTType] = [UTType.text, UTType.data]
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes, asCopy: true)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
       
        self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

In the output we can see transparent view between "Recent/Browser" tab bar and document content view.

Here is the screenshot of the output:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wI4g.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74exM.png)

If I change the presentation style to fullScreen,  transparent view will become grey coloured view

```
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

Here is the screenshot of the fullScreen output:

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEC37.png)
[image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlkwH.png)

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Check `UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent` property.
I had the same problem when this property was `false`